# How to get the keycloak token via swagger

Tags: swagger, keycloak, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger (in nodejs) to make REST APIs with the (keycloak) token using bearerAuth securitySchemes. I have to set the token before calling requests, and it works.

I want to create a call with username and password fields to get the token, instead of retrieving it via postman.

If I try with openId (instead bearerAuth) I have this error: Auth error TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. (in the log - CORS Missing Allow Origin).
Could you help me?

Comment: I could call a POST call using openId, but I need to add the CORS plugin in my chrome browser. Without it I have this error: "Access to fetch at xxx from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: I'm using app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocs)); - is there way to set the CORS policy?

Comment: I have solved my problem. I had to set the Web Origins with * inside client-id in Keycloak